# How to get a button on Facebook post that opens an app directly?

Tags: ios, facebook, app-store, facebook-page

I´ve seen some Facebook posts that include a native button which opens the corresponding app to the Facebook page that created the post.

When the app is not installed, it links out to the App Store. When it is installed, it deeplinks into the app to the desired content.

How can I achieve this? I searched for some information about this, but couldn´t find any.

Answer (score 1):

you have to try the App Links functionality that Facebook provide. In the developer page teach how to create and use this and you will see the flow when somebody press a post for example and how the redirection is produced:

[image]

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/applinks/ios

You have to create an app in the Facebook Developer Console and enable de deep-linking function to works.

Regards!